# css/html- to create a circle with a hole in the bottom

Tags: svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzIR5.png)

I wanna make circle chart like this.
below is my code.

If I invert up and down in that code, i get the shape you want.
But what I really want is a graph with the yellow graph pointing further to the right. How do I adjust the spacing?
Please help me

```
<svg width="4.5rem" height="4.5rem" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle class="pieSegment segment1" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.915494309189533" fill="transparent" stroke="#1a0d1c" stroke-dashoffset="11" stroke-dasharray="74" stroke-width="5"></circle>
  <circle class="pieSegment segment3" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.915494309189533" fill="transparent" stroke="#e9ad61" stroke-dashoffset="14" stroke-dasharray="25 75" stroke-width="5"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: why you tag as html and css? your code is only svg

Answer (score 0):

an idea can be to use `pathLength="100"` to your circle
that allow you to give a percent in the attribute stroke-dashoffset  with `100% - {percent of circle to fill}`

then we can imagine rotate the circle to the correct shape

```
#mySvg {
  transform: rotate(-125deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

to round the border of your line you can use

```
  stroke-linecap: round;
```

```css
#mySvg {
  transform: rotate(-125deg) scaleX(-1);
}

#mySvg circle {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySvg" width="4.5rem" height="4.5rem" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle class="pieSegment segment1" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.915494309189533" fill="transparent" stroke="#1a0d1c" stroke-dashoffset="20" stroke-dasharray="100" stroke-width="5" pathLength="100"></circle>
  <circle class="pieSegment segment3" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.915494309189533" fill="transparent" stroke="#e9ad61" stroke-dashoffset="80" stroke-dasharray="100" stroke-width="5" pathLength="100"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I adjust the spacing to make the yellow graph go a little further to the right?

Comment: in my sample you just have to play with stroke-dashoffset of segment3 the calculation is `100 - {percent of circle to fill}`

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit (missed the previous answer by @jeremy-denis also using pathLength)

Here is another approach also using `pathLength` value:
See also [MDN Docs: pathLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength)

### example horse shoe gauge

```js
let progress = document.querySelector("#progress");
let svgGauges = document.querySelectorAll(".svgGauge");
let gauges = document.querySelectorAll(".gaugePercent");
let percentText = document.querySelector(".percentText");

progress.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let percent = e.target.value;
  if (svgGauges.length) {
    svgGauges.forEach(function(item, i) {
      let currentGauge = svgGauges[i];
      let gauge = currentGauge.querySelector(".gaugePercent");
      let dashGap = gauge.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray").split(" ")[1];
      // console.log(gauge);
      gauge.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", percent + " " + dashGap);
      gauge.setAttribute("style", "animation-fill-mode: none");
      percentText.textContent = percent;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.gaugeWrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
}

.layout {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.txt-cnt {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  transition: 0.3s;
  stroke-width: 15;
}

.linecap-round .circle {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

.linecap-round .circle[stroke-dasharray^="0 "] {
  stroke-linecap: unset;
}
```

```html
<p class="txt-cnt">Progress (<span class="percentText">50</span>&thinsp;%) <input id="progress" style="width:100px" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="50" />
</p>
<div class="layout">

  <div class="gaugeWrap">
    <p>horse shoe gauge 270°</p>
    <svg class="svgGauge linecap-round" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-225) ">
      <circle class="circle gaugeBG" id="gaugeBG" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="133.333" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="100 100" />
      <circle class="circle gaugePercent " id="gauge" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="133.333" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="50 133.333" stroke="#e9ad61" />
    </svg>
  </div>


  <div class="gaugeWrap">
    <p>Semi-circle gauge 180°</p>
    <svg class="svgGauge linecap-round" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-180)">
      <circle class="circle gaugeBG " id="gaugeBG" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="200" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="100 200" />
      <circle class="circle gaugePercent" id="gauge" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="200" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="50 200" stroke="#e9ad61" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gaugeWrap">
    <p>Full-circle gauge 360°</p>
    <svg class="svgGauge" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(-90)">
      <circle class="circle gaugeBG" id="gaugeBG" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="100 100" />
      <circle class="circle gaugePercent" id="gauge" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45" pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-dasharray="50 100" stroke="#e9ad61" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Your example has approximately a 270° range (3/4 of 360°).
By setting `pathLength`to 133 (360/270*100) we change the computation of the dash lengths.
Since we don't use the complete circumference of the circle (see the full circle example with pathLength=100) we increase the pathlength to make this 3/4 segment to have a length of 100 units.

We can set the first `stroke-dasharray` value e.g. to 50 (display 50% progress).
The 2nd value 133 ensures the dash gap is large enough to fill the rest of the circle gauge.

To make the horse shoe gauge stand upright we need to calculate a rotation like this:

(360 + 270)/2 - 90 = -225

So we can rotate the parent svg by setting the transform attribute to
`transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-225)"`

[Gauge generator pen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/dyVMvXM)